# Can anyone explain me what this "grammar" variable holds and what is the function of "nltk.RegexpParser()"?

Tags: python, regex, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

```
def extract_NN(sent):
    grammar = r"""
    NBAR:
        # Nouns and Adjectives, terminated with Nouns
        {<NN.*>*<NN.*>}
    NP:
        {<NBAR>}
        # Above, connected with in/of/etc...
        {<NBAR><IN><NBAR>}
    """
    chunker = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
    ne = set()
    chunk = chunker.parse(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sent)))
    for tree in chunk.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.label() == 'NP'):
        ne.add(' '.join([child[0] for child in tree.leaves()]))
    return ne
extract_NN(text)
```

Comment: `grammar` is a multiline string which is used as input for the `RegexpParser` function

Comment: you can check the documentation of `RegexpParser` [here](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.chunk.html)